# Smarty not changing until Apache server restart

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, smarty

I have Smarty integrated into Zend and it's using Zend Cache with Smarty saving cache into separate folder.

When I make changes to the smarty or PHP codes with Zend, it seems the only way to see those changes is to restart `httpd` which isn't ideal.

Is there a better way? Perhaps turning cache off and/or refresh so I can see changes made both on PHP and Smarty?

According to Zend documentation, there seems to be backend and frontend caching with Zend Cache.

Comment: i think even smarty has its own caching system.. maybe you need to disable it? see this: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Smarty has it's own caching. Usually `templates_c` directory keeps the compiled templates. Try also clearing that. You can also go into the smarty class and change the setting so when the template is changed it will know on page refresh. In Smarty.class.php change this below to `true`.

```
   var $compile_check   =  true;
```

I would turn that back off in production so that it doesn't slowdown your site any.